# Running R file using sh/bash

Tags: r, carriage-return

I have created below .sh file to run R code saved in separate .R file.

```
cat EE.sh
#!/bin/bash

VARIABLES=( 20190719 20190718 )

for i in ${VARIABLES[@]}; do
        VARIABLENAME=$i
        /usr/lib/R/bin/Rscript -e 'source("/home/EER.R")'
```

Basically what it is expected to do is, take the dates from VARIABLE and pass to the `/home/EER.R` file, and R will do execution based on passed date (after correct formatting)

Then I ran below code

```
sudo chmod a+rx EE.sh
```

and

```
sudo bash EE.sh
```

But I then get below error message.

> sudo bash EE.sh
>   EE.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
>   EE.sh: line 3: $'\r': command not found
>   EE.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

I am using `Ubuntu 18 with R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)`

Comment: Please do a `cat -v Input_file` you seems to have carriage returns in your file. If you find it then run `tr -d '\r' < your_script > temp && mv temp your_script` to remove them.

Comment: you can also set R to read command line arguments with ``` args=commandArgs(TRUE); varriable=args[1]; .... ``` and use those variables inside your R script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem looks to be related to carriage returns related(which come when we copy text from windows machine to unix machine), so to identify them use:

```
cat -v Input_file
```

If you see carriage returns in your file then try:

```
tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

Once they are removed then try to run your program.